# TypeScript: Signature for '???' is duplicated

Tags: cordova, windows-8, typescript, winjs

1. Create a WinJS windows 8 application
2. Add the windows 8 phonegap javascript library to the project
3. Add the d.ts phonegap typescript definition library from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped
4. Add a script.ts file to the project
5. type the following

Code:

```
///<reference path="phonegap.d.ts" />

var x = 1;
```

Now if you "compile" the script.ts file in VS I get the following error

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/TypeScript/lib.d.ts(4551,4): 
Signature for 'clearWatch' is duplicated
```

In my VS 2012 I also have the following extension installed (which may be related to the issue but not sure)

- TypeScript
- Web Essentials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is both **lib.d.ts** and **phonegap.d.ts** has a method called `clearWatch` in the `Geolocation` interface.

I suggest you to comment out this method from **phonegap.d.ts**

Comment: I have submitted a pull request to Definitely Typed to update `phonegap.d.ts`. https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/230